# How to setup Spring Cloud Data Flow security

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

How could I setup Spring Cloud Data Flow security (login page, user, pass,...)
I have tried to use these following properties in application.properties but it does not work:

```
security.basic.enabled = true
security.basic.realm = Spring Cloud Data Flow
security.user.name = admin
security.user.password = admin
security.user.role = VIEW,CREATE,MANAGE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review the [security configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-oauth2) section from the reference guide in entirety.

There's no true basic-auth as an option that is provided in SCDF. It used to be in 1.7.x, but that has been deprecated in favor of OAuth+OIDC standardization since SCDF 2.0.x. That means you will have to use an OAuth identity provider to set up your custom authentication and authorization workflows.

You could use the `Password Grant Type` supported by OAuth2+OIDC as the mechanism to mimic the username+password-based authentication workflow. UAA can be used as an identity provider, as well. We have a [sample on this subject](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example).

Comment: security in Spring is quite new to me. Could you give me some more simple sample?

Comment: That means spring-boot-starter-security does not work for SCDF?

Comment: SCDF is a full-blown application. We ship a binary, its an uber-jar. And, the application already builds on Spring Security and several other upstream security projects to provide coherent security scopes and roles for granular access controls for the CRUD operations in SCDF.

Comment: Can I use my adsf server to replace for uaa server in your example?